# How to detect being source'd as opposed to being run in a shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

In python you can detect whether a script is executed as opposed `import`ed by another script with this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We are run directly.
```

Is there a way in to do the same in a shell script?
I have a couple of functions in script that I would like to be able to source, without executing them.

Comment: Why not just keep the safe stuff such as function declarations and env variables in the sourced file, and move any executing code to a different script file?

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to have any real relevance to the tag python, remove that tag?

Comment: @HåkenLid when a task calls for separating in multiple files, I tend to start thinking that maybe it's too big for a shell script. Unless it's about cluttering my .profile of course. ;-)

Comment: Did you try searching for a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced

Comment: @barny I'm looking for the shell equivalent of something in Python. https://stackoverflow.com/q/573585/383793 is also tagged both [git] and [svn]

Comment: @123 yes, but nothing useful came up... How did you find this one?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling went on google and searched `check if script is sourced`

Comment: @123 ah. I used the SO search.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've come up with these:

```
if [ "$0" != "bash" ]
then
    # We are run directly because
    # $0 == our filename
    # Or is it? It could be a different shell!
fi
```

and

```
if [ "$(basename $0)" = "foo.sh" ]
then
    # We are run directly, because $0 == our filename.
    # But what if we get mv'ed to some other filename???
fi
```

Are there any less brittle solutions?

Comment: Your first solution seems fine. If you want to support other shells, just add them to the condition.